# Value does not fall within the expected range. Observabledictionary. Windows phone 8

Tags: dictionary, binding, observable

```
<Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot">
    <StackPanel
        Margin="30, 30, 10, 0"
        HorizontalAlignment="Left">
        <ComboBox
            x:Name="FacultyComboBox"
            Width="210"
            Header="Факультет:"
            HeaderTemplate="{ThemeResource ComboboxHeaderTemplate}"
            ItemsSource="{Binding Timetable[0].Faculties, Converter={StaticResource FacultyListToStringListConverter}}"
            SelectedIndex="{Binding Timetable[0].SelectedFaculty, Mode=TwoWay}"
            PlaceholderText="Выберите факультет"/>
        <ComboBox
            x:Name="GroupComboBox"
            Header="Группа:"
            HeaderTemplate="{ThemeResource ComboboxHeaderTemplate}"
            ItemsSource="{Binding Timetable[0].CurrentGroups}"
            SelectedIndex="{Binding Timetable[0].SelectedGroup, Mode=TwoWay}"
            PlaceholderText="Выберите группу"/>
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Timetable[0].SelectedGroup}" FontSize="20"></TextBlock>
    </StackPanel>
</Grid>
```

When I add SelectedIndex="{Binding Timetable[0].SelectedGroup, Mode=TwoWay}" the error appears. w/o this line everything is ok, but I very need this line.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I found the solution. The point was that u can't bind several elements to same Data Source just like that, but u need to set the DataContext parameter at a parent element, so u could bind to certain fields of same Data Source.
Hope, this will help somebody like me.